# Insert random number AND selected rows (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

As the headline states, I'd like to know how to insert both a random number generated with php, and selected lines from another table. Example:

```
<?php
$randomid = (rand(1,1000000));

$sql = "INSERT INTO example2 (randomid, userid, name)
        VALUES ('$randomid')
        SELECT userid, name
        FROM example1
        WHERE name='Donald' "

$mysqli->query($sql);

?>
```

I'm not sure how to go about this. Must I divide this into an insert and an update query?

Comment: `SELECT` can be used to output messages/static values in MySQL so you should be able to do `"SELECT ".$randomid.", userid, name"`. but ofcause MySQL has it's own random function `RAND()` but it only returns a decimal number between 0 and 1 so you'll want to multiple it by 1000000 and `FLOOR` it to get a random integer

Comment: Got it, thanks. Put it as an answer and I'll give you a best answer mark!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT` in MySQL can be used to output message/static values like in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91114/2)

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN userid<100 THEN 'less than 100'
    WHEN userid<200 THEN 'less than 200'
    ELSE 'greater than 200' 
END AS message, userid
FROM mytable
```

so in your example you can just do the same

```
$randomid = (rand(1,1000000)); // <--- imagine 25 was returned

$sql = "INSERT INTO example2 (randomid, userid, name)
        SELECT ".$randomid.", userid, name
        FROM example1
        WHERE name='Donald' " // <--- you select now looks like 'SELECT 25, userid, name'
```

however there is a downside as this will give every entry with the `name` Donald the same value so if you have multiple Donalds it kinda defeated the purpose of a random value unless you plan to limit the insert to do one at the time giving your PHP `rand` function to recalculate

a better way to do this is with MySQL's own [`RAND` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)

> Returns a random floating-point value v in the range 0 <= v < 1.0.

ofcause since this function returns a decimal/float value which isn't really ideal for an integer key we want to make it into a inetger by mutiplying it and using `FLOOR` by using this

```
FLOOR(RAND()*1000000) AS randomid
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/91114/4)

this will get us a value between 0 and 1, we multiply it by 1000000 and then round it down to the nearest full number using `FLOOR` and unlike the PHP code a new number is created for every entry. so 15 Donalds will have 15 different random ids. there is still the possibility that you can get identical number but thus is the nature of random number

Comment: Elaborate! Thank you very much.